# Double integral of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \, dx \, dy$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have the double integral $∫∫_D1/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\,dx\,dy$, where $D$ is the domain given by $1\le x^2+y^2\le4$.

I've tried setting $x = r\cos\theta, y=r\sin\theta$. I don't know if this  is the right procedure. And even if it is, I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Are you aware of Jacobian?

Comment: Yes, I am. How should I implement it in this case?

Comment: Your integral is $\int_0^{2\pi}\int_1^2\tfrac 1 r|\det J(r,t)|\,dr\,dt$, where $J$ is the Jacobian of $(r,t)\mapsto (r\cos t,r\sin t)^T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's definitely a good start! Note that your integration range will be $0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$ and $1 \le r \le 2$. You want to calculate the [Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant); see in particular [this example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant#Example_2:_polar-Cartesian_transformation). Hopefully this should allow you to proceed! :)

---

Your original domain $D$ is a full 'doughnut' (or annulus) around the origin. The parameter $1 \le r \le 2$ indexes the full 'width' of the annulus. The reason we take $0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$ is that we need to go all the way 'around' the circle.

Comment: It's $1\le r\le 2$.

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but can you tell me why the range for $\theta$ is $0$ to $2\pi$?

Comment: Because $r(\sin\theta,\cos\theta)$ only parametrizes a circle with radius $r$ if you go around once, that is, from $0$ to $2\pi$ or from $-\pi$ to $\pi$. This leads me to the question whether you actually know how your integration domain $D$ looks like.

Comment: Yeah, no problem! I've just edited the answer to include some more details. If you need any more help, just ask! :)

Comment: @Sam T I don't think OP learns anything if you tell them everything.

Comment: @amsmath I agree. Hence why I showed them the answer in parts, first explaining the Jacobian and leaving the rest. If the OP then asks for further clarification, I'll give it. I would note that your comment (which I've only just seen), which is almost the same as my edit, came slightly before my edit. If you read my other answers (and questions), you'll see that I stand firmly by the 'give hints' not 'give answers' mantra.

Answer (score 0):

The expression $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ looks pretty convenient to parametize.
So letting $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=r$ your integral becomes $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{1}^{2} \frac{1}{r}|det(J)|drd\theta$$
Where $det(J)$ is the determinant of the [Jacobian Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant). For variables $x,y$ the determinant is $r$.

So your integral becomes:$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{1}^2 \frac{1}{r}(r)drd\theta=2\pi$$

Comment: Why do you still integrate over $D$ in the first integral? This is not correct. Also, you should use the absolute value of $\det J$, in general.

Comment: My bad, I corrected it.

Comment: In general, what does the $det(J)$ represent?

Comment: We told you may times already. It is the determinant of the Jacobian.

Comment: I know that. I meant what does the determinant represent?

Comment: Next time, if you ask more clearly, you'll get the answer right away. $|\det J|$ represents the correction that has to be made when you change variables. You do the same when you do substitution on integrals.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I learned a lot from it! :)